# UserNotifications related events

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

I am working with an iOS app using UserNotifications.

When the user taps on a notification, this method is fired:

*userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)*

I want to know if there is a method called when the notification arrives, independently of when the user reacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter
Of course the app has to be open for that. you can not execute code if the app is closed.
In some cases you can execute code if the app is in background but that required special authorisation.

Comment: I see. I just tried, but as you mention it just works if the app is running. At least it would be useful if it could run in the background to log the arrival of a notification for instance. Otherwise its use is very limited. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The point of this method tho is to allow the app to provide a custom experience when a notification arrives. Like updating an in app icon, or asking to redirect to another section of the app, ...

Comment: OK, in the present case I would like to be able to log the arrival time of a notification, even while in the background.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, and I'm not sure of the advantage of it either. What is you r end goal, except logging the time it arrives?

Comment: That is the goal. I want to know the "the time it arrives". When the notification is triggered by location and the user is moving, this is very valuable information.